# QSQLDatabase doesnt open connection to Microsoft SQL Database (QT, Linux, C++)

Tags: c++, sql-server, linux, qt, odbc

I have a problem with debugging my software.
I installed the Package libqt4-sql-odbc after i found out my QT cant find the ODBC driver.
After installation the Error is away.

### For connecting i made

```
QSqlDatabase db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setHostName("The IP Adress of the MSSQL-Database");
db.setDatabaseName("the Databasename");
db.setUserName("The Database accountname");
db.setPassword("the Database account password");
db.setPort(1433);

if(db.open())
{
    qDebug()<<"open Database";
}
else
{
    qDebug()<<"closed Database";
}
```

---

after starting the application and executing this method i always get the Debug-Message "closed Database")

What did i wrong?
Maybe i installed wrong the ODBC?
Should i use ODBC3?
is the host-name as IP correct or cant i take the IP of the database?

Comment: I suggest you add qDebug() << db.lastError() near the message "Closed databas"

Comment: QSqlError(0, "QODBC3: Unable to connect", "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified")

Comment: related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222302/how-can-i-connect-mssql-database-with-qt-4-8-6

Comment: i installed freetds but dont find /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so

Comment: I am not that strong in Windows stuff, but I think you have setup some kind of configuration in ODBC, probably you have to create a connection named QODBC3 and in there specify everything you need to connect to the database.

Comment: What ODBC Driver did you install?